# My queue program doesn't display elements after inserting

Tags: c, queue

I tried adding elements to the queue but when display elements function doesn't work. Also when I click on delete without inserting any element, it doesn't execute the if statement I made for empty queue.
I don't know where the problem is but please help me resolve this issue.

This the function for inserting queue elements:-

```c
int num;
if(rear==MAXSIZE-1)
{
    printf("\nQueue is full (Queue overflow)");
    return;
} else {
    if(front==-1)
        front=0;
    printf("\nEnter the element to be inserted : ");
    scanf(" %d", &num);
    rear++;
    queue[rear] = num;
}
```

This is the function for deleting queue elements:-

```c
if(front==-1 && front > rear)
{
    printf("\nQueue is empty (Queue underflow)");
    return;
} else {
    int num;
    num=queue[front];
    printf("\nDeleted element is : %d",num);
    front++;
}
```

This is the function for displaying queue elements:-

```c
if(front==-1)
{
    printf("\nQueue is empty (Queue underflow)");
} else {
    printf("\nQueue elements are : \n");
    for(int i=front; i<=rear; i++)
    printf("%d\t",queue[i]);
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. You don't show "the function"s but only code snippets that could be the function bodies. We don't know the data types, how you call the functions and what data you use. Please [edit] your question and create a [mre], i.e. a program we can compile and run together with example input, the actual output you get and the expected output.

Comment: `if(front==-1 && front > rear)` <<-- ???

Comment: `if(front==-1 && front > rear)` is logically incorrect.  At the very least, the `&&` should be `||`.

Answer (score 0):

Queues are normally built as circular buffers, so enqueueing and dequeueing is much more comfortable. I just found an implementation [here](https://github.com/charlesdobson/circular-buffer). This looks like the code you are searching for.